# Estimates for higher order derivatives of the Airy Kernel

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, special-functions, linear-pde

Consider the kdv equation (from [here](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4939-2181-2))
$$\left\{\begin{array}{l}
\partial_{t} v+\partial_{x}^{3} v=0 \\
v(x, 0)=v_{0}(x)
\end{array}\right.$$
Its solution can be written as $v(t,x)=S_t*v_0(x),$ where $x,t\in \mathbb{R}$ and
$$S_{t}(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{3 t}} A i\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt[3]{3 t}}\right).$$

I would know already know that the following estimates hold:

\begin{aligned}
&|A i(x)| \leq \frac{1}{\left(1+x_{-}\right)^{1 / 4}} e^{-c x_{+}^{3 / 2}}, \\
&\left|A i^{\prime}(x)\right| \leq\left(1+x_{-}\right)^{1 / 4} e^{-c x_{+}^{3 / 2}}
\end{aligned}

however, I was wondering if in general one knows how to bound the $k$-th derivative of the Airy function for $k\in \mathbb{N}$ and $k\geq 2?$